# Print IntInf.int

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj, ml

I'm trying to get SML/NJ to print out a large integer of type **IntInf.int**.

However the function `print(Int.toString(some_large_int))` does not work because `Int.toString` works only for the int type and not the IntInf.int.

Is there any way to print IntInf in the stdout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use IntInf.toString() instead.